# Comparability of topologies on $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\cal C=\{[a,b):a<b; a,b\in \Bbb Q\}$ be a basis for a topology on $\Bbb R$. [This](https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-13-basis-for-a-topology/problem-8-solution/) says that topology generated by $\cal C$ is not comparable to [the countable complement topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) on $\Bbb R$.

But I think that topology generated by $\cal C$, call it $\cal T(\cal C)$ is finer than the countable complement topology: the basis elements $B$ for the countable complement topology are at most countably many elements removed from $\Bbb R$, for example, $\Bbb R-\{0\}$ is a basis element for the countable complement topology. So, if $x\in B$, then there is an element of $\cal C$ such that $x\in [a,b)\subset B$ where $a$ and $b$ are rationals.

Comment: Yes, but $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is just ***one*** basis element for the countable complement topology. You need to show that ***every*** basis element of the countable complement topology is open in $\cal T(\cal C)$. Let's see you do it for $B=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q.$

Comment: Wow ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only take *one* basis element of the countable complement on $\mathbb R$ and prove that it is an element of $\tau(\mathcal C)$.

That is not enough.

You must at least prove that all elements of a a randomly chosen subbase of the cocountable topology are elements of $\tau(\mathcal C)$.

From the fact that $\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ is evidently not an element of $\tau(\mathcal C)$ (in contrast to non-empty elements in $\tau(\mathcal C)$ it does not contain an interval) it can be concluded that $\tau(\mathcal C)$ is not finer than the cocountable topology.

Comment: Tanks for this answer. What is $\tau(\mathcal T)$ in second last line?

Comment: A typo (I repaired). You are welcome.